# Getting HTTP 404 not found error while invoking action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Please find the below details of my application

```
public class CartController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Response<CartDto> GetById(Guid customerId)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

In *WebApiConfig.cs*

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

URL

`http://localhost:50300/api/Cart/GetById/customerId=5D5020DA-47DF-4C82-A722-C8DEAF06AE23`

When I call the action method using the above URL, I am getting the HTTP 404 Not Found. What went wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you change `customerId=5D5020DA-47DF-4C82-A722-C8DEAF06AE23` to `?customerId=5D5020DA-47DF-4C82-A722-C8DEAF06AE23`

Comment: Yes, you were correct. After changing the slash to question mark before customerId in the url, it worked fine. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The URL

```
 api/Cart/GetById/customerId=5D5020DA-47DF-4C82-A722-C8DEAF06AE23
```

and the action parameter name `customerId` does not match the route template

```
api/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Update action

```
[HttpGet]
public Response<CartDto> GetById(Guid id) {
    //....
}
```

and URL should follow template

```
api/Cart/GetById/5D5020DA-47DF-4C82-A722-C8DEAF06AE23
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your URL was the missing `?` to indicate the start of your querystring:

```
http://localhost:50300/api/Cart/GetById/?customerId=5D5020DA-47DF-4C82-A722-C8DEAF06AE23
```

Everything after the `?` is in the querystring, and gets matched up by name (i.e. `customerId` gets matched to your parameter of the same name).